# How do I call a parent function inside a nested function in lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Consider this code sample:

```
var helper = {
  isCheetah: function(a) {
    return a === "Cheetah";
  },

  isLepoard: function(a) {
    return a === "Lepoard";    
  },

  researchedSpecies: function(a) {
    return this.isCheetah(a) || isLepoard(a);
  },

  getResearchedSpecies: function(allSpecies) {
    return _.filter(allSpecies, this.researchedSpecies);
  }
};

// prints "isCheetah: true" 
console.log("isCheetah:" + helper.isCheetah("Cheetah"));

// complains "this.isCheetah is not a function
helper.getResearchedSpecies(["Zebra", 
                             "Cheeta", 
                             "Lepoard",
                             "Godzilla"]);
```

<sup>Here is a live code on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/liyohumewe/edit?js,console</sup>

This works okay without lodash, in normal functions. Throw lodash into the mixute and the nested level functions no longer work. I guess it is because the `this` keyword, when invoked by lodash, doesn't refer to parent anymore, but to lodash instead (is that correct?).

Anyway, how do I work around that? How do I call the parent functions in a nested function invoked by lodash?

Comment: `_.filter` accepts third parameter as context binding. Try passing the third parameter `this` to your `_.filter` call

Comment: Alternatively, bind the function reference to `this` using `Function#bind`. [See this edit.](http://jsbin.com/dogubiguzo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: (And see [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for _why_  you need to do this).

Comment: @sdgluck excellent, that works... can you put both your comments in an answer please

Comment: @RahilWazir, great, thanks, you could put that in an answer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by OP, copied from comments:

Bind the function reference to `this` using `Function#bind`.

[Here is an updated JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/dogubiguzo/1/edit?js,console)

See [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for why you need to do this.